# type hinting with Unions and collectables 3.9 or greater

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

I've been on Python 3.8 for quite some time. I usually type hint with the convention:

```py
from typing import List, Union

some_stuff: List[Union[int, str, float, List[str]]] = [98, "Fido", -34.925, ["Phantom", "Tollbooth"]]
```

I understand that with python 3.9 or greater you can type hint lists and collectible like: `some_ints: list[int]`

If you have a union of types that a variable can occupy do you still need to import the `Union` class? like so:

```py
from typing import Union

some_stuff: list[Union[int, str, float, list[str]]] = [98, "Fido", -34.925, ["Phantom", "Tollbooth"]]
```

Or is there a new convention for Union type hinting as well?

Comment: What do you mean? Your second snippet still imports `Union`. And what does whether you using `List` or `list` have to do with unions?

Comment: My question, is how you type hint unions still the same, even given the new list convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PEP 604](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/), which was implemented in Python 3.10 allows `Union` types to be formed using the `|` operator (which has existed with exclusively numeric meanings for most of Python's history).

So in sufficiently recent versions of Python, you can write your type hint like this, with no imports required from `typing`:

```
some_stuff: list[int|str|float|list[str]] = [98, "Fido", -34.925, ["Phantom", "Tollbooth"]]
```

While that specifically answers your question, I'd note that it's a little suspicious that your example data exactly matches the order of the types you're listing in the `Union`. If you are always going to have exactly one of each kind of data (rather than some unknown mixture of them), you probably want to be type hinting the value differently, e.g. with `tuple[int, str, float, list[str]]` which specifies that there will be one value of each, in that order. You might need to use an actual tuple for the value, I'm not sure there's a way to hint a fixed pattern of values within a list object.

Answer (score 4):

If you import

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

you can use the union types with `|` syntax starting from Python 3.7, without errors.

```
$ python3.7 -c 'from __future__ import annotations; a: int | str = 42'
```

If you don't use the [`__future__` import](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html) to enable new [PEP 563 behavior](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/), Python evaluates the annotations at runtime and you get an exception because prior to 3.10, types don't define the `|` operator.

When using `__future__` import, you need to rely on your IDE or running `mypy` to catch incorrectly formatted annotations. Use sufficiently new mypy that supports this new syntax.

(For reference, here's what happens without the `__future__` import.)

```
$ python3.7 -c 'a: int | str = 42'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'type'
```